# How can I sync data on my device storage with data on server when I have internet connection

Tags: ionic3

I am designing an Ionic app and I want functionality as below.

I have one form on page of app and I collect data which I store in internal storage using following ionic-native api

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file'
```

I am interested in posting that data to server when I get connected to Internet regardless of app state i.e app is open or closed .

Comment: By sync you mean data will have to be constantly transferred between the server and the app ?

Comment: yes ,whenever i have internet connection

Comment: You could take a look at [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/). It might offer a ready-made solution for your problem...